# How to view all wiki-less tags

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Is there a way to view all tags on a specific SE site that do NOT have an associated wiki entry? Bonus points for sorting by number of questions tagged!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Follow-up question: how to search for the quickest question closures? :)

Comment: too easy! http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84210/the-fastest-closed-questions